# Single menu link not translating

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

I am working with a site which uses many different languages. When switching languages there is always one main menu item which doesn't translate, but the title on the page it links to does translate (menu title and page title are both the same).

The main menu mostly consists of a number of links to taxonomy terms, but this single troublesome link is to a node.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Any chance you could tell us the name of it? I had something similar when i tried to name a menu-item "print" which was automatically translated into the used language...

Answer (score 1):

did you translate the site using any module

go for Content Translation core module: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/translation